# How to find all the namespaces with incorrect relatively to their location names in a solution?

Tags: c#, namespaces, visual-studio-2013, refactoring

I am looking for a technique to find all the wrong namespace in solution.

With wrong namespace I mean all the namespaces that have a different from the current location.

For e.g.: If I have a project called MyCompany.MyProject.Frontend and I have a class under the Controller folder, the final namespace should be:
**MyCompany.MyProject.Frontend.Controller**

How can I find all the namespaces that doesn't follow this standard?

I know that Resharper offers this feature but currently we don't have a license for it.

Is there any free solution to this problem?

Comment: Use Ctrl + F, or use the Object Browser.

Comment: I didn't know which are all the wrong namespaces, so I don't thinks it's possible to just use the Find feature. The Object Browser could be a solution ma I would prefer something more automatic to discover the wrong ones

Comment: @simoneL - Do you mean to say "If my project is namespace X, and I have a class in folder Y, the class should be in namespace X.Y"? Your example has a class in the Controller folder that you assert should have the namespace ..FrontEnd.FrontEnd; I expected you to say it should be in FrontEnd.Controller.

Comment: Yep, sorry, wrong copy and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just download and install the trial version, do what you need, and be then get rid of R#?

Otherwise, writing a simple parser with a search and replace shouldn't be hard, just "fiddly" and time-consuming to get exactly right.

However, as soon as you do this, you are going to run into the problem that all of your previous includes statements will need to be modified to include the new namespaces, which R# will do for you as part of it's operations.

Seriously, just use R# as a free trial, and get what you need from it.  Even better, just buy  a copy for yourself... I've gotten my $150 worth.